# how to add a percentage to grouped data?

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning pandas and struggling with how data is organized in that module.

I follow the tutorial and docs to handle a basic task: percentages of occurrence of a state ('color') within bins ('site'). The code below hopefully clarifies what I have and want to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# example of a few first entries generated below: 
# [('site2', 'red'), ('site3', 'red'), ('site1', 'yellow'), ...
sites = ['site1', 'site2', 'site3']
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']
d = []
for i in range(0,100):
    s = (
        sites[random.randint(0, 2)],
        colors[random.randint(0, 2)],
    )
    d.append(s)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.columns = ['site', 'color']

grouped = df.groupby(['site', 'color'])
p = grouped.size()

# the whole group
print(p)
# the number of instances of 'blue' in 'site2'
print(p['site2']['blue'])
# the total number of instances for 'site2'
print(p['site2'].sum())
```

The output is as expected: "for a given site, show the number of events with a specific color"

```
site   color 
site1  blue      16
       red       11
       yellow     6
site2  blue       9
       red       12
       yellow    12
site3  blue      11
       red        7
       yellow    16
dtype: int64
9
33
```

What I am trying to achieve is to generate a new column in the grouped data with the percentage of a given color for a given site. In practical terms, this would be for the example above

```
site1  blue      16 48.4
       red       11 33.3
       yellow     6 18.2
site2  blue       9 27.3
(...)
```

I clearly have the numbers to make the calculation (the last two outputs are an example), I do not know how to actually loop though the group to add the calculated percentages.

`p = grouped.size()` type is `Series`. Could I somehow enrich it with the calculated percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be calculated by dividing the [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) by the [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas.Series.sum) on the first level of your index:

```
In [38]:

grouped.size() / grouped.size().sum(level=0) * 100
Out[38]:
site   color 
site1  blue      25.714286
       red       45.714286
       yellow    28.571429
site2  blue      32.432432
       red       43.243243
       yellow    24.324324
site3  blue      32.142857
       red       39.285714
       yellow    28.571429
dtype: float64
```

Of course, my output above will be different to yours due to the random input values.

**EDIT**

It's more readable to pass the name of the level you wish to sum by:

```
In [46]:

grouped.size() / grouped.size().sum(level='site') * 100
Out[46]:
site   color 
site1  blue      25.714286
       red       45.714286
       yellow    28.571429
site2  blue      32.432432
       red       43.243243
       yellow    24.324324
site3  blue      32.142857
       red       39.285714
       yellow    28.571429
dtype: float64
```